# Rails render error with Missing partial test/test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the base structure html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Layout</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- UI Object -->
        <div id="wrap">
            <p>
                #wrap
            </p>
            <!-- header -->
            <div id="header">

                <p>
                    #header
                </p>

            </div>
            <!-- //header -->
            <!-- container -->
            <div id="container">
                <p>
                    #container
                </p>
                <!-- snb -->
                <div class="snb">
                    Login
                    <input/>
                    <input/>
                    <button>
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
                <%=render "test/test"%>
                <!-- //snb -->
                <!-- content -->
                <!-- <div id="content">
                    <p>
                        #content
                    </p>

                </div> -->

                <!-- //content -->
            </div>
            <!-- //container -->
            <!-- footer -->
            <div id="footer">
                <p>
                    #footer
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- //footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- //UI Object -->

    </body>
</html>
```

in here, the "content" part will be the dynamic part, that will be changed.

So i used `<%=render "test/test"%>` to render code in,

/views/test/test.html.erb

but if i run this,

it throws on error like this,

```
Missing partial test/test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
```

Of course, i tried to put that params like this,

```
<%= render :partial => 'test/test', :locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee] %>
```

but still have the same error.

Any good solution?

Comment: partial filenames should start with `_`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rename your **/views/test/test.html.erb** file to **_test.html.erb**. And it will works :)

Comment: Z Thanks for the fast response. Another quick simple question. If i program with this base structure. Every filename will be like _something.html _another.html...This looks really weird. I don't think this is the right way to code. I think i'm going the wrong way :(

Comment: Only partial name must be _name. It's rails :) Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Partial files should be named with leading '**_**', like **_test.html.erb**.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Another quick simple question. If i program with this base structure. Every filename will be like _something.html _another.html...This looks really weird. I don't think this is the right way to code. I think i'm going the wrong way :(

Comment: @Canna not "every filename", but "every partial filename" and it's completely ok.

Answer (score 0):

The partial file names should be prefixed with underscore(_).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that the question had already been answered. Sorry for duplicating the content.